# Why the code contains error when creating excel file and want to work with it

Tags: c#, excel, comparison, filtering, variable-assignment

The entry was:

Create a C# code with the following requirements:

We have 3 sheets with the following names: (records, consumption_kardex, tool_lists). The code will ask for two values when it is started, the first value is for "part number" and the second value is for "operation". After the user enters these two values, the code will filter the column "I" in the records table based on the first value. Then it will filter the column "E" based on the second value. Next, it will calculate the sum of all values in columns F and G in the records table (the sum will be calculated after the I and E column filters are applied). This value will be written to the fourth sheet, column A, which will be created with the name "comparison.xlsx".

Then, the code will filter column A in the tool_lists sheet based on the user-entered first value (part number). In the tool_lists sheet, the code will then multiply columns D and E (D * E) and add all the results of this multiplication together into one result. This result will be written to column B in the fourth sheet named comparison.

Next, in the tool_lists sheet, where we will use filtering again in column A, we will take the values in column B from row 2 and filter column B with them in the consumption_kardex sheet. Then, in the filtered consumption_kardex sheet, we will calculate the sum of the values in column C and write them to the fourth sheet comparison in column C.

The error is at line 17, here is the code:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Získáme vstupní hodnoty od uživatele
            Console.WriteLine("Zadejte číslo dílce:");
            string cisloDilc = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Zadejte operaci:");
            string operace = Console.ReadLine();

            // Vytvoříme nový sešit s názvem "srovnani.xlsx"
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            workbook.SaveAs("srovnani.xlsx");

            // Vytvoříme instanci třídy Worksheet pro každý sešit
            Worksheet worksheet1 = workbook.Worksheets["zaznamy"];
            Worksheet worksheet2 = workbook.Worksheets["nastrojove_listy"];
            Worksheet worksheet3 = workbook.Worksheets["spotreba_kardex"];

            // Vyfiltrujeme sloupec "I" v tabulce "zaznamy" podle hodnoty "cisloDilc"
            worksheet1.Range["I1:I"].AutoFilter(cisloDilc);

            // Vyfiltrujeme sloupec "E" v tabulce "zaznamy" podle hodnoty "operace"
            worksheet1.Range["E1:E"].AutoFilter(operace);

            // Vypočítáme součet hodnot ze sloupců "F" a "G" v tabulce "zaznamy"
            int soucet = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= worksheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                soucet += Convert.ToInt32(worksheet1.Cells[i, 6].Value) + Convert.ToInt32(worksheet1.Cells[i, 7].Value);
            }

            // Zapíšeme součet do sloupce "A" v tabulce "srovnani"
            worksheet2.Cells[1, 1].Value = soucet;

            // Vyfiltrujeme sloupec "A" v tabulce "nastrojove_listy" podle hodnoty "cisloDilc"
            worksheet2.Range["A1:A"].AutoFilter(cisloDilc);

            // Vypočítáme součet hodnot ze sloupců "D" a "E" v tabulce "nastrojove_listy"
            soucet = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= worksheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                soucet += Convert.ToInt32(worksheet2.Cells[i, 4].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(worksheet2.Cells[i, 5].Value);
            }

            // Zapíšeme součet do sloupce "B" v tabulce "srovnani"
            worksheet3.Cells[1, 2].Value = soucet;

            // Vyfiltrujeme sloupec "B" v tabulce "nastrojove_listy" od řádku 2
            worksheet2.Range["B2:B"].AutoFilter(cisloDilc);

            // Vyfiltrujeme sloupec "B" v tabulce "spotreba_kardex" podle hodnot ze sloupce "B" v tabulce "nastrojove_listy"
            worksheet3.Range["B1:B"].AutoFilter(worksheet2.Range["B2:B"]);

            // Vypočítáme součet hodnot ze sloupce "C" v tabulce "spotreba_kardex"
            soucet = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= worksheet3.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                soucet += Convert.ToInt32(worksheet3.Cells[i, 2].Value);
            }

            // Zapíšeme součet do sloupce "C" v tabulce "srovnani"
            worksheet3.Cells[1, 3].Value = soucet;

            // Uložíme sešit "srovnani.xlsx"
            workbook.Save();

            Console.WriteLine("Srovnání dokončeno.");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for help.

I tried to create excel file and I excepted, that it will create without problems.

Error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Třída není zaregistrována (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

On the line of:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
```

Maybe my VS2022 is set wrong.

**EDIT 13.10.2023**

This is my code now:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Získáme vstupní hodnoty od uživatele
            Console.WriteLine("Zadejte číslo dílce:");
            string cisloDilc = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Zadejte operaci:");
            string operace = Console.ReadLine();

            // Vytvoříme nový sešit s názvem "srovnani.xlsx"
            var oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            if (File.Exists("C:\\Users\\11uadber\\Desktop\\appvs\\srovnani.xlsx"))
            {
                File.Delete("C:\\Users\\11uadber\\Desktop\\appvs\\srovnani.xlsx");
            }
            var workbook = oXL.Workbooks.Add();
            workbook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\11uadber\\Desktop\\appvs\\srovnani.xlsx");

            // Vytvoříme instanci třídy Worksheet pro každý sešit
            Worksheet worksheet1 = workbook.Worksheets["C:\\Users\\11uadber\\Desktop\\appvs\\zaznamy.xls"];
            Worksheet worksheet2 = workbook.Worksheets["C:\\Users\\11uadber\\Desktop\\appvs\\nastrojove_listy.xlsx"];
            Worksheet worksheet3 = workbook.Worksheets["C:\\Users\\11uadber\\Desktop\\appvs\\spotreba_kardex.xlsx"];

            // Vyfiltrujeme sloupec "I" v tabulce "zaznamy" podle hodnoty "cisloDilc"
            worksheet1.Range["I1:I"].AutoFilter(cisloDilc);

            // Vyfiltrujeme sloupec "E" v tabulce "zaznamy" podle hodnoty "operace"
            worksheet1.Range["E1:E"].AutoFilter(operace);

            // Vypočítáme součet hodnot ze sloupců "F" a "G" v tabulce "zaznamy"
            int soucet = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= worksheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                soucet += Convert.ToInt32(worksheet1.Cells[i, 6].Value) + Convert.ToInt32(worksheet1.Cells[i, 7].Value);
            }

            // Zapíšeme součet do sloupce "A" v tabulce "srovnani"
            worksheet2.Cells[1, 1].Value = soucet;

            // Vyfiltrujeme sloupec "A" v tabulce "nastrojove_listy" podle hodnoty "cisloDilc"
            worksheet2.Range["A1:A"].AutoFilter(cisloDilc);

            // Vypočítáme součet hodnot ze sloupců "D" a "E" v tabulce "nastrojove_listy"
            soucet = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= worksheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                soucet += Convert.ToInt32(worksheet2.Cells[i, 4].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(worksheet2.Cells[i, 5].Value);
            }

            // Zapíšeme součet do sloupce "B" v tabulce "srovnani"
            worksheet3.Cells[1, 2].Value = soucet;

            // Vyfiltrujeme sloupec "B" v tabulce "nastrojove_listy" od řádku 2
            worksheet2.Range["B2:B"].AutoFilter(cisloDilc);

            // Vyfiltrujeme sloupec "B" v tabulce "spotreba_kardex" podle hodnot ze sloupce "B" v tabulce "nastrojove_listy"
            worksheet3.Range["B1:B"].AutoFilter(worksheet2.Range["B2:B"]);

            // Vypočítáme součet hodnot ze sloupce "C" v tabulce "spotreba_kardex"
            soucet = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= worksheet3.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                soucet += Convert.ToInt32(worksheet3.Cells[i, 2].Value);
            }

            // Zapíšeme součet do sloupce "C" v tabulce "srovnani"
            worksheet3.Cells[1, 3].Value = soucet;

            // Uložíme sešit "srovnani.xlsx"
            workbook.Save();

            Console.WriteLine("Srovnání dokončeno.");
        }
    }
}
```

And the problem is on this line now:

```
Worksheet worksheet1 = workbook.Worksheets["C:\\Users\\11uadber\\Desktop\\appvs\\zaznamy.xls"];
```

Error code:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Neplatný index. (0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
```

**EDIT 13.10.2023 14:55**

Now I have error on this line:

```
worksheet1.Range["I1:I"].AutoFilter(cisloDilce);

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 0x800A03EC
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the error details.

Comment: Did you install Excel library? Or do you have Excel installed?

Comment: I have excel istalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get Excel app:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Získáme vstupní hodnoty od uživatele
            Console.WriteLine("Zadejte číslo dílce:");
            string cisloDilc = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Zadejte operaci:");
            string operace = Console.ReadLine();

            // Vytvoříme nový sešit s názvem "srovnani.xlsx"
            var oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            var workbook = oXL.Workbooks.Add();
            workbook.SaveAs("srovnani.xlsx");
            ...
```

Addendum I

```
            var wb1 = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\11uadber\\Desktop\\appvs\\zaznamy.xls")
            var worksheet1 = wb1.Worksheets["Prostěradlo1"];
```

Use the required worksheet name or index instead of "Prostěradlo1" dummy.

Comment: I dont understand this.

Comment: @user22728505 Basically, you can't just create a `Workbook` object on its own. You first need to create an Excel Application object, and then use that object to create your new workbook, as in the answer. The error you are getting is because while the `Workbook` object has a COM interface, you cannot create one directly (technically, it doesn't have its own Class Factory).

Comment: could you edit my code? its impossible for me to do it...

Comment: Modified for you.

Comment: Thank you, its working, i will continue and tell you know.

Comment: Can you accept my answer?

Comment: yes, I edited now my original post, I have another error

Comment: If you need to open a workbook (from file), use the `Workbooks.Open` method: `oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\11uadber\\Desktop\\appvs\\zaznamy.xls")`

Comment: You provided the file name to get a sheet. You need to use a worksheet name instead. The typical worksheet name is "Sheet1" or "Prostěradlo1".

Comment: I need to load workbooks (.xlsx and xls) into variables and work with them, for this may I use Open method? And where I have to provide sheet names which are inside workbooks?

Comment: I dont understand how to do it, first I have to Open excel file and then initialize worksheet variable?

Comment: Extended the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I added one more edit.

Comment: I see you do not fully understand what you need to do. I suggest you to start your efforts from Excel. First try to manually execute all actions you need. Then redo it from the beginning recording macro. You will get the code on VBA which will be about ready to use in your application with some corrections and find&replace.

Comment: I need to filter columns and then sum their values

Comment: "I1:I" is the wrong name for an Excel range. Start do it in Excel, you'll get everything correct.